# Reading graph GML files using jGraphT

Tags: java, parsing, graph-algorithm, jgrapht

I'm trying to run Dijkstra's algorithm on a graph. I need to read a graph modelling language (gml file into my Graph, Vertex and Edges Data structures).
The gml file is somewhat like this
graph
[
  directed 0
  node
  [
    id 0
    label "BrighamYoung"
    value 7
  ]
  node
  [
    id 1
    label "FloridaState"
    value 0
  ]
.
.
.
.
Does java have any library that can read this data into my classes?. Or any suggestions on creating a parser in java?. I'm trying out jgraphT but can't seem to figure it out. There's a class GMLImporter but I don't understand how to use it. It requires Vertex Provider and Edge provider. Please suggest some workarounds!

Answer (score 1):

In the 1.0.0 release from Sept 2016 we have included brand new GML importer/exporters. Using them is very easy. Every class in Jgrapht comes with an extensive test suite (just to make sure we don't break anything in between releases). The nice thing about these test classes is that they contain a ton of examples. See for instance the class `GmlImporterTest.java`.

Example: read a Undirected Weighted graph from a GML file:

```
Graph<String, E> g=new SimpleWeightedGraph<String, E>(DefaultWeightedEdge.class);

VertexProvider<String> vp = new VertexProvider<String>()
        {
            @Override
            public String buildVertex(String label, Map<String, String> attributes)
            {
                return label;
            }
        };

        EdgeProvider<String, E> ep = new EdgeProvider<String, E>()
        {

            @Override
            public E buildEdge(String from, String to, String label, Map<String, String> attributes)
            {
                return g.getEdgeFactory().createEdge(from, to);
            }

        };

        GmlImporter<String, E> importer = new GmlImporter<String, E>(vp, ep);
        importer.importGraph(g, new File("myGraph.gml"));
```

The `VertexProvider` and `EdgeProvider` tell the importer how to create the vertex/edge objects.